# Embedding HTML Code in XSL FO Using Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle-apex, xsl-fo

I am using oracle APEX for web applications. I have created sample Report Query and Report Layout for PDF printing in APEX.
Report Query is "`Select 'ab<b>cd</b>ef' content from dual;`"

Report Layout(XSL-FO) is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="2.0">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <fo:root>
         <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4" page-width="216mm" page-height="279mm" margin-top="3cm" margin-bottom="1cm" margin-left="1cm" margin-right="1cm">
               <fo:region-body margin="0.0cm" />
            </fo:simple-page-master>
         </fo:layout-master-set>
         <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
               <fo:block margin-left="0.5cm" margin-right="0.0cm" margin-top="0.0cm" font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" color="#000000" text-align="center">
                  <xsl:apply-templates disable-output-escaping="yes" select="DOCUMENT/ROWSET/ROW/CONTENT" />
               </fo:block>
            </fo:flow>
         </fo:page-sequence>
      </fo:root>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Below is APEX generated XML Data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DOCUMENT>
<ROWSET>
   <ROW>
      <CONTENT>ab&lt;b&gt;cd&lt;/b&gt;ef</CONTENT>
   </ROW>
</ROWSET>
</DOCUMENT>
```

I am getting PDF output as "`ab<b>cd</b>`" which means getting output with tags,
However i need PDF output as "ab**cd**ef".

I have tried disable-output-escaping="yes", it is not working.

Please let me know if any further details are required.

Thanks,
Siva

Comment: Is your XML data accurate?  You show `&amp;lt;b&amp;gt;` for `<b>` but `&lt;/b&gt;` for `</b>`.  It would be unusual for a start-tag to be generated with different escaping than its end-tag.

Comment: Thanks for Quick response. Apologies for existed xml. below is my xml, apologies for existed xml. below is my xml <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DOCUMENT>
<ROWSET>
   <ROW>
      <CONTENT>ab&lt;b&gt;cd&lt;/b&gt;ef</CONTENT>
   </ROW>
</ROWSET>
</DOCUMENT>